# Implementing menu in a game made with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to make a menu for my game. It works the first time i open the game and when the player dies it goes into `menu()` as expected. But when i press "start game" after the player has died once, it executes `main()` for less than a second then goes back to `menu()`. Heres how i made the menu

```
def menu():
    controls = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\final game\controls.png").convert()
    controls.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    controls = pygame.transform.scale(controls, (1200, 600))
    back_rect = pygame.Rect(800, 550, 400, 50)
    back_rect_border = pygame.Rect(800, 550, 400, 50)
    start_rect = pygame.Rect( 400, 200, 400, 100)
    start_rect_border = pygame.Rect( 400, 200, 400, 100)
    controls_rect = pygame.Rect(400, 310, 400, 100)
    controls_rect_border = pygame.Rect(400, 310, 400, 100)
    x = 1200
    loop = True
    display_controls = False
    while loop:
        D.fill((255,173,96))
        events = pygame.event.get()
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if not display_controls:
            if start_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                start_color = (200, 150, 0)
                for event in events:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        loop = False
                        run_menu = False


            else:
                start_color = (100, 200, 150)

            if controls_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                control_color = (200, 150, 0)
                for event in events:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        display_controls = True

            else:
                control_color = (100, 100, 150)

            pygame.draw.rect(D, start_color, (start_rect))
            pygame.draw.rect(D, control_color, (controls_rect))
            pygame.draw.rect(D, (0, 0, 0), (start_rect_border), 3)
            pygame.draw.rect(D, (0, 0, 0), (controls_rect_border), 3)
            write(50, "START  GAME", (255, 255, 255), 404, 220)
            write(50, "CONTROLS", (255, 255, 255), 404, 330)



        if display_controls:
            D.blit(controls, (x, 0))
            x -= 10
            if x<= 0:
                x = 0

            if back_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                back_color = (200, 180, 182)
                for event in events:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        display_controls = False
                        x = 1200

            else:
                back_color = (254, 219, 183)

            pygame.draw.rect(D, back_color, (back_rect))
            pygame.draw.rect(D, (0, 0, 0), (back_rect_border), 3)
            write(25, "BACK TO MAIN MENU", (255, 255, 255), 802, 555)



        win.flip()
```

Now in my `if __name__ == "__main__":` i ran menu and the main function like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    menu()
    main()
```

The `main()` is just a bunch of function calls:

```
def main():

        def handle_events(events):
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    game.bullets.append(Bullet())

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                            if not  game.fireballs:
                                    game.fireballs.append(Fire_ball())

        while True:

             events = pygame.event.get()

             handle_events(events)

             D.fill((254, 219, 183))

             game_map.draw()

             player.draw()

             player.move()

             player.camera()

             player.boundries()

             player.jetpack()

             game.fall_player()

             player.draw_jet_bar()

             player.draw_health_bar()

             player.dead()

             game.shoot_bullet()

             game.shoot_fireball()

             game.destroy_bullet()

             game.spawn_enemy()

             game.move_enemy()

             check_fireball_hit()

             game.destroy_fireballs()

             check_bullet_hit()

             print_stats()

             mouse.update()

             scroll[0] += 1

             win.flip()
```

The `player.dead()` function in `main()` is supposed to trigger the menu after the player dies (and this is the part that's not working) and it looks like this:

```
 def dead(self):
        if self.hp  <= 0:
            menu()
```

This is my first  time creating menu for a game so i has not sure what would be the best way to do it. It dosent work once the player has died meaning the problem is in `player.dead()` function which triggers the menu. Any help would be  appreciated. Thanks

Edit:
I figured its because the player's is still 0 or less than 0 the next time i press start game, which forces the menu to execute. Now my question is how do i reset all the stats in the game once the player has died. Is there any way to start a fresh execution of main all over again once the player has died?

Comment: Could you add more details on how this is not working? Does it work the first time the player dies, and not the second? Does anything happen when you expect the menu to come up, or does the program stop running or hang?

Comment: I made a few changes at the start

Comment: Ahh i thinnk i figured it out, Its because the player's is still 0 or less than 0 the next time i press start game, which forces the menu to execute. Now my question is how do i reset all the stats in the game once the player has died. Is there any way to start a fresh execution of main all over again??

Comment: What I would do it write some new functions like `player.reset()` and `map.reset()` that will do things like restore your character to full health, move them to the start location, repopulate map resources etc...  this will be a lot easier to deal with in the long run than trying to keep your variables all within `main()`'s scope (which would let you just rerun `main()` for a new game, but gets hard to manage as the game grows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these sorts of things, a common approach is a set of States and (maybe) Transitions.  Often you see these drawn as diagrams:

[image: state-transition-diagram]

Admittedly, it's a rather simple set of states.  But maybe you'd have in-game states too, like (perhaps) "loading", "level1", "level2", etc.

So the current state is kept in a variable, and the main loop uses the value to decide what to do.  If the program is in "menu" state, the menu is painted, and arrow-keys change the highlighted choice.  Whereas if the game is in "playing" state, the arrow keys are used to move the player-character, etc.

```
menu_state = 1
current_state = "menu"
while current_state != "exit":

    # paint the screen
    if ( current_state == "menu" ):
        drawMenu()
    elif ( current_state == "game" ):
        drawGame()

    # Handle Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            current_state = "exit"
        elif ( event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ):
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if ( current_state == "menu" ):
                current_state = handleMenuClick( mouse_pos )
            elif ( current_state == "game" ):
                game.bullets.append( Bullet() )

    # Handle continuous-key-presses, but only in menu mode
    if ( current_state == "menu" ):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
            menuSelectPrevious()
        elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
            menuSelectNext()
        elif ( keys[pygame.K_ENTER] ):
            current_state = menuDoOption()

    print_stats()
    win.flip()
```

This gives a simple method for allowing functions to always "know" the state of the game, and what states are permissible to change-to from the current state.  This helps untangle all the possible options on say, handling an event.  It also means you need only *one* event loop, which greatly simplifies the program flow.